# return empty vector by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, vector

I'm returning a vector by reference as shown below and it is getting bit ugly when I want to return an empty vector when there is no item in the map. The following gives warning (`returning address of local variable`) and to fix it, I have another private member variable `vector<ClassA> empty_` and I could return it to avoid this.

I am wondering if there is elegant way to implement this.

```
const std::vector<ClassA>& GeVector(const std::string& class_id) {
auto iter = class_map_.find(class_id);
if (iter != class_map_.end())
    return iter->second;
return {}; // return empty_;
}

private:
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<ClassA>> class_map_;
vector<ClassA> empty_;
```

Comment: Your `empty_` is an elegant way of doing this. Could make it static for good measure.

Comment: Return a pointer, which could be `nullptr`.

Comment: @john nullptr doesn't work. fails to compile.

Comment: @RedFox pay attention to the first sentence.

Comment: The warning is correct - you return a reference to local variable tat will cease to exist after the function call. Your local `empty_` is a decent solution. The function can also throw an exception or return a pointer instead of a reference (failure to compile is not a blocker)

Answer (score 9):

You could use a static variable:

```
static const std::vector<ClassA> empty;
return empty;
```

Comment: static function-scope variables bear (a minuscule) performance hit. Class level static doesn't have this drawback.

Comment: @SergeyA but class level static suffers from static initialisation order fiasco.

Comment: Not in this case.

Comment: @SergeyA why not?

Comment: Ok, I should rephrase it - not with the code provided.

Comment: @SergeyA well, the code provided does nothing since `GeVector` is never called. But it is just an example. If `GeVector` is called from initialisation of a static object defined in another TU than where the suggested static member is defined, the order of initialisation will be unspecified. Not a problem with a local static.

Comment: Like I said - than you have performance hit. Best solution is to actually use initialization guard, like `std::cout` uses. That would be supposedly overkill here.

Answer (score 3):

If your method support the option of failure you could throw a exception instead of returning an empty vector.

```
const std::vector<ClassA>& GeVector(const std::string& class_id) {
    auto iter = class_map_.find(class_id);
    if (iter != class_map_.end())
       return iter->second;

    throw std::exception("Element not found"); // or similar
}
```